Medspacy can not detect any entity although it exists
I am working in a text that contains biomedical entities. However medspacy package failed to detect those:
import medspacy

nlp = medspacy.load()    
text = "The patient was treated with warfarin for atrial fibrillation."
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(f"Entity: {ent.text}, Label: {ent.label_}")
print("Total Entities: " + str(len(doc.ents)))

Output:
Total Entities: 0

I am trying to check if any pipeline exists for entity detection:
print(nlp.pipe_names) and I can layout the pipelines: ['medspacy_pyrush', 'medspacy_target_matcher', 'medspacy_context']. How to resolve this problem?

You'd also need a TargetMatcher to the pipeline to detect the entities. Here's the code snippet:
import medspacy
from medspacy.ner import TargetMatcher, TargetRule

# Load medspacy pipeline
nlp = medspacy.load()

# Initialize a TargetMatcher
target_matcher = nlp.get_pipe("medspacy_target_matcher")

# Create TargetRule objects for entity patterns
target_rules = [
    TargetRule("warfarin", "MEDICATION"),
    TargetRule("atrial fibrillation", "CONDITION")
]

target_matcher.add(target_rules) 

And the rest of the code remains the same:
text = "The patient was treated with warfarin for atrial fibrillation."
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(f"Entity: {ent.text}, Label: {ent.label_}")
print("Total Entities: " + str(len(doc.ents)))

Outputs:
Entity: warfarin, Label: MEDICATION
Entity: atrial fibrillation, Label: CONDITION
Total Entities: 2

Automated Detection: You can use scispaCy's NER models for this, which are fine-tuned for biomedical, scientific or clinical text. I tested with the en_ner_bc5cdr_md model which you can download via:
pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.0/en_ner_bc5cdr_md-0.5.0.tar.gz

and then use this snippet:
import spacy # version 3.7.6

nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bc5cdr_md")
text = "The patient was treated with warfarin for atrial fibrillation."
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(f"Entity: {ent.text}, Label: {ent.label_}")

print(f"Total Entities: {len(doc.ents)}")

to get this result:
Entity: warfarin, Label: CHEMICAL
Entity: atrial fibrillation, Label: DISEASE
Total Entities: 2 


Thank you very much for you answer! However, I was thinking to detect the medical entities automatically without seeing the data. Here, rule is based on the given data. Is there any way to do it?

I updated my answer to include an approach for automated detection with scispaCy. Please feel free to try other models from their repo to suit your needs. As these models are fine-tuned on different text corpus, they may produce different results.
